# Resolve Merge conflict issue on remote git

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm using bitbucket.

I have two branches on local and remote : `feature/BRANCH_A` and `TEST_BRANCH`

On local :
I checkout the `feature/BRANCH_A`, created a temporary branch for merging and merged this temporary branch to `TEST_BRANCH` as follows

```
git checkout feature/BRANCH_A
git checkout -b merge_BRANCH_A_to_TEST_BRANCH
git merge TEST_BRANCH
```

at this point i got merge conflicts in few files, so i manually resolved the conflicts and committed the changes in `merge_BRANCH_A_to_TEST_BRANCH`

I then pushed this temporary branch to remote

```
git push merge_BRANCH_A_to_TEST_BRANCH
```

I was then able to view the latest merge related commit of this temporary branch on remote branch (did this to ensure that the files containing conflict are updated even on remote)

Now, when i give pull request from `merge_BRANCH_A_to_TEST_BRANCH` to `TEST_BRANCH` on bitbucket, i get conflicts on the same files.

I'm not sure about how to proceed further and resolve this error.

Comment: A bit unsure if you got the wording in this question wrong or not. When you execute `git merge TEST_BRANCH`, you're not merging **to** TEST_BRANCH, you're merging TEST_BRANCH into the branch you're currently on, so you just merged TEST_BRANCH into erge_BRANCH_A_to_TEST_BRANCH. Can you verify if this is a misunderstanding you have and that it might explain what you're observing? `git merge x` merges **from** x, not *to* x.

Comment: However, if you did a proper merge when you merged TEST_BRANCH into merge_BRANCH_A_to_TEST_BRANCH, and resolved all conflicts, and the commit you made is a merge commit, all commits on TEST_BRANCH should now be on that branch, so if you merge this branch back into TEST_BRANCH, there should be nothing to merge, just a fast-forward. Why you're getting a merge conflict here is unknown. Can you clarify that you ended up with a proper merge commit on that merge_BRANCH_A_to_TEST_BRANCH branch?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen my mistake was since i was doing half of this via command line and other half using the atom IDE, the merge was not committed in the first place and hence the error. After resolving that, it was exactly like what you are describing in the second comment. Thank you for your prompt response and help.